# Get the terms from a custom taxonomy without posts

Tags: wordpress, function, taxonomy

What I am asking is, is there a built-in function that gets the the result of the following mysql query? `get_terms()` seems to get only the terms that are assigned e.g. to a post and not the whole list.

```
select 
    name
from
    wordpress.wp_terms
where
    term_id in (select 
            term_id
        FROM
            wordpress.wp_term_taxonomy
        where
            taxonomy = 'custome_taxonomy')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have a misunderstanding about [`get_terms`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_terms) and don't know the purpose of the arguments within `get_terms`

By default, all terms without posts are hidden, here is the argument

```
'hide_empty'    => true,
```

To retrieve terms without posts, you'll need to pass false to the `hide_empty` argument, like this

```
$terms = get_terms( 'hide_empty=false' );
```

Comment: Works Thanks. I am new to wordpress so I did not understand what empty terms meant.